# Overcurrent Sensing

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-measurement, current-limiting, current-sensing

I am designing an overcurrent protection circuit. I am sensing current with a LEM sensor across a sensing resistor of 16.5 ohm. The voltage drop for maximum current is 2 V. In the next stage I am using INA301A1 (CMVR 0 - 36 V, unipolar power supply 0 V / 3.3 V). This IC has a fixed gain of 20 V/V. Now for full scale drop of 2 V, my output will be saturated (40 V), so I need to I need to step down 40 V To 3.3 V.

What is the best way to do it?

I am thinking about using a potential divider between sense resistor stage and overcurrent IC stage but using a lower (10s of ohm) resistance divider may load my sense resistor and higher (kohms) might load input of IC.

Are these apprehensions plausible and what could be a possible solution?

Answer (score 4):

> What is the best way to do it?

The best way is to do what every engineer is doing in circuits like this - using as small shunt resistor as possible. 16 Ohm is **not** a "sensing resistor", it is unnecessary load. Current shunts typically in range of a few mOhm to 1 Ohm, which results in correct voltage drop in mV range (250 mV for INA301A1).

From your numbers the maximum current seems to be 120 mA, so 2 Ohm shunt will give you correct 250 mV voltage drop.

UPDATE

There was a misunderstanding corrected in the comments below. It turns out the OP does not measure voltage on shunt resistor in the actual high power circuit, but rather voltage drop on burden resistor of current transducer.

Taking this new information into account two solutions were suggested:

- adjust burden resistor to bring voltage swing into full-scale range of ADC input and use any OP Amp in comparator configuration for overcurrent signal generation;
- same as above but drop the overcurrent signal altogether and use MCU comparator input to generate interrupt on threshold. This would eliminate all external components except for one burden resistor.

All of the above assumes uni-directional current, implied by original use of INA301 chip. Bidirectional sensing requires more complex circuit, as discussed in @TonyEErocketscientist answer.

Comment: I am using a LEM sensor with 1:2500 turns ratio which gives me a max sec. current of 120mA. So 16.5ohm limits my losses to 250mW. So I don't think it's an unnecessary load. I do agree that I can further decrease the resistance to reduce input voltage drop as you suggested ( also because the input offset voltage is very low and gives me that liberty while maintaining high measurement accuracy) but the sensor I am using is LA305s (LEM hall effect sensor) and it's datasheet specifies a lower limit of 5 ohm for measurement resistance (due to thermal protection of output power stage of transducer)

Comment: THe std IC conductive current sensor may be high side or low side is about 50 to 75mV then amplified to your scale.  A passive magnetic current sensor only needs a burden R and Hall sensors are also ok. But your question fails to mention Hall sensor and datasheet link

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist INA301 has standard versions with 50 and 100 mV ranges, but for some reason OP is using a version with 250 mV. Although it does have better linearity of the three.

Comment: https://www.lem.com/sites/default/files/products_datasheets/la%20305-s.pdf 5 ohms*120mA=600mV secondary

Comment: Even using the lowest specified burden resistance of 5 ohm, I will get a full scale voltage drop of 600mV , resulting in 12 V at the output of INA301A1. Although, I just realised that I am using a bipolar 15V supply for transducer which limits my lower burden resistance. Changing it to +-12V, I can reduce my burden upto 0ohm and then it could be possible to achieve smaller voltage drop as suggested  by Mapple  and you.

Comment: OK, now I am really confused. What on earth do you need that INA301 for, if LA305 already provides voltage suitable for ADC? Simply adjust your resistor to get full ADC range and be done with it.

Comment: I need INA for overcurrent Sensing as I mentioned in the title. Sorry if the question created some misunderstanding

Comment: Ah, you mean you only using comparator output, not the voltage (which you can get from LA305)? In this case any OP Amp will do. And if you need voltage too, then you can adjust resistor to get voltage swing that you need and use comparator for digital overcurrent signal only. INA301A1 is an overkill for this

Comment: Yes. I do need the voltage output of resistor as well, which I will have to input in an ADC and as you suggested I will resize my resistor for 3V full scale voltage for ADC. Regarding the overcurrent, you suggest that I should use any opamp where I should set threshold for overcurrent and compare it with burden output to get a digital signal. Did I understand you correctly? Also can u suggest an opamp

Comment: Yes, you got it right. Or, better yet, **use comparator input if your MCU has one**. It can be programmed for interrupt on threshold. I believe this would be simplest, cheapest and easier to tune-up solution. As for OP Amp selection in case you go with external comparator, I think @TonyEErocketscientist would be able to give much better advice. My guess, rail-to-rail inputs with single supply 18V and up should do the trick. Something like LT6015, OPA191, OPA197 etc.

Comment: I'm thinking any 1 of quad Op Amp will do as it is low speed with single supply and Rail to Rail. But I would do things differently with bipolar logic OCP using a window detector to detect both polarities or a full wave precision rectifier with one threshold for logic level out and signal condition the Diff Amp to match the signal spectrum of all events needed to be detected.

Comment: That would be definitely necessary if bidirectional sensing required. Shifting the drop to ADC range and implementing OCP in both polarities could be quite complex circuit, comparing to simple LA305 + MCU combination. I guess its a choice between user-friendly and budget devices.

Comment: Overcurrent with MCU does seem like the most hassle free solution but I want to use overcurrent signal to trip my input relay with hardwire and not software (also I am using FPGA for closed loop current control).

Comment: Well, in that case use external comparator. Although internal comparator plus ISR is awfully close to hardware solution, IMHO. And using FPGA when you have MCU is strange too, unless you need super-tight current control with uA precision

Comment: Maple you shud correct your assumptions on Burden R.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using a fixed gain INA, use a gain and offset DIff Amp OA design to scale your input to the desired output.

if 0 to 2V in and 0 to 3.3V out  then non-inverting  gain = 1.65

If -2V to +2V in and 0 to 3.3V out then gain = 0.825 and offset = +1.65V (=Vss/2)

I suspect you want to measure high current AC primary so you want to measure both polarities > +/- x.xx V  so you compute dual thresholds y using Vdd/2 as a null reference.

[image]

But keep in mind radiated CM noise.  Having 120 dB CM conducted noise rejection is wasted if the cable is only 50dB CMRR with a 500A impulse going thru a Rogowski coil, so choose your cable **wisely**.  that is already 50dB above your current sensor secondary.  Getting 100 dB attenuation of Injected H field current impulse near the cable may depend on doubled shielded twisted pair with a Pi filter CM Choke and orthogonal orientation.  *This is what I have had to use in the past with monitoring 10kA arc welders.*

### opinions and design specs?

For the OCP logic output, I would ask if real-time and polarity is important. Because, knowing the high Remanence Currents from saturation on power up due to the phase difference and resulting magnetization V difference between power input stop and restart, start current can be quite large if starting 180 phase shifted and make some Xfmr's  "hum" for a long time until unsaturated or return to zero averarge magnetization current.  Also Arcs can be polar so a single-sided OCP logic output  does not use all the useful information available on different faults.

Comment: I agree with you. I picked INA because it ensures inbuilt impedance matching for differential amplifier and also gives a digital output for overcurrent which can set with a single resistor

Comment: Yes but so does a properly designed diff amp with 3 stages in a quad OA. and is not limited to 20

Comment: Ok, got your point

Comment: digital output? where ? + or - current?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist I believe INA301 does not work with AC. Even though pins can tolerate +/- 40V the differential input is specified 0..250mV, so current is one direction only. The overcurrent output is open drain

Comment: Yes I see now the dual output, but comparator is only +ve polarity  inputs Vin*20> DAC input threshold.  This could be done with 0.1% R divide gain = 0.825 /20, but OCP assumes symmetrical currents ( unlike random Remanence effects from Xfmr supply outage ) and glitches missed such as an arc.

Comment: My application has nominal unidirectional currents of upto 200A, 40kHz. The aim is to do two things: first to do implement closed loop current control with FPGA and second is to isolate the my converter (buck-boost) in event of an overcurrent. So as per discussion here, for first target, I  sized my burden resistor to give a full scale drop of 2.5V and with a dual amplifier IC (first stage buffer and second stage non inverting LPF), I should get a full scale voltage of 2.75 V Which I can feed into my ADC.

Comment: For overcurrent protec, leaned towards INA301A  as it seemed less complex. So to be able to use INA I need to step down 2.5V to 200mV. For that I use OPA191 as unity gain  (to not load my burden res) & then  pot divider of 500 ohm and 5.7k to get 200 mV and feed that as input to INA. Do u see any  issues with this solution? Can you comment that since INA301 input res must be in Mohm so either of those two res. shouldn't cause any loading issues at the input of INA. Should I use bypass cap or not at the input pin of INA given unity gain conf of stage 1 as capacitive loading issues(not sure)

Comment: The purpose of my design is to satisfy buffering, gain and offset. The 4th Op Amp can be a comparator. The R inputs can use 1M 0.1% for ~60dB CMRR. Normally an INA does this better as the 1st stage.  Impedances for R and stray C must be balanced on remote sources and well shielded (STP cable, do not gnd shield at the source to other equip.)  You can use a DC and 50/60Hz blocking cap with a breakpoint of 1kHz or so. If any RF then use front-end LPF for 400kHz 1 decade up to avoid potential issues of ESD diodes rectifying any RF or impulses.

Comment: I thought you might use a DAC voltage to adjust offset which also changes Comparator level with a fixed threshold as I have indicated in my schema.

Comment: I have dumped INA but one very naive question. Why did you suggest a difference amplifier whereas using a dual amplifier IC with first stage as buffer and second stage for comparison with threshold voltage with 0.1% resistor for setting gain. To me that we much simpler, quicker and offering lower footprint. What is the benift of designing it with difference amplifier with four precision resistor

Comment: A unity gain buffer might saturate with CM noise greater than the signal.  So a Diff Amp suppresses the CM noise with an error in ratio or dB according to the R tolerances.  Which is why laser trimmed INA's are better but the one you selected is too high gain, but has the convenience of a comparator.  Think of how a 10:1 scope probe is balanced and what happens to response when imbalanced.  THen try two probes and subtract on a large signal. How much is remaining is the error of calibration or if too high gain, saturation in each amplifier.

Comment: When very high  currents are sensed nearby the sensor cables the opportunity for imbalanced magnetic mutual coupling is great.  Even though power lines are far from the magnetosphere and pretty high above the ground,  a  meter difference is enough to cause catastrophic grid events with magnetowobble so each phase is twisted every k m.  (rotate positions with respect to ground.)  But these are very low voltages but over a great length so differential induction  is significant and can fault a transformer with DC.